# Flow server problems

Tags: react-native, flowtype

I've started a new React Native project with `expo init`, using the `tabs` template; and then followed the instructions at https://flow.org/en/docs/install/ to get Flow up and running, including `yarn run flow init`.

When I run `yarn run flow` for the first time, I get VS Code alerts saying the server is the wrong version, and another alert below it, saying the server has stopped. As I'm typing these sentences, those two alerts are disappearing and reappearing again and again.

Here's a weird thing. Here's my .flowconfig file.

```
[ignore]

[include]

[libs]

[lints]

[options]

[strict]
```

No version number at the end, no nothing.

When I run `yarn run flow` again it gets no errors, which is good although it makes sense as well because my `src` folder is empty.

The alerts give me options to `restart client` or `restart`. Let's see:

Restart client run `yarn run flow`: launches a new server, which gives the same alert in VS code, that it's the wrong version, the alert disappears and reappears again and again.
Same thing happens when I click "restart" instead of "restart client"

---

I'm using flow in the first place (at first, before I use it myself) to import some of the F8 code from makeitopen.com. I copy `[F8Stylesheet.js][1]` from the F8 repo, into my `src` folder. Red lines appear under the type annotations, saying types can only be used in a ts file (I have installed the Flow Language Support) extension.

When I run `yarn run flow` I get a whopping 188 errors! I've only copied in this ONE file from the F8 repo and the errors are coming from files like `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/Switch/SwitchNativeComponent.js`, which weren't having problems until I pasted in this one file.

Here's my package.json file, by the way:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll",
    "build": "babel src/ -d lib/",
    "prepublish": "yarn run build"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.95.1",
    "jest-expo": "^32.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Any help anywhere? Thanks.